# Algorithm to distribute set of numbers in 2D array without neighboring themselves

Tags: arrays, algorithm, computation-theory, computation

i  want algorithm to distribute a set of numbers like (0,1...15) in big 2D array with known dimensions without letting the number neighboring itself as example :

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7

3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13
```

if you look to any number you will never see it neighboring itself in any direction ?

Comment: are diagonals included in the direction?

Comment: yes.it's included.

Comment: do the numbers have to be distributed equally? For example, would the numbers 0-15 show up approximately the same number of times in the array?

Comment: no.they don't have to but it will be more efficient to distributed mostly equal.

Comment: @AhmedMohsin take the first 9 numbers from the set and put them inside `array`. Now `map[x][y] = array[x%3 + 3 * y%3]`. This only uses the first 9 numbers from your set but if thats not a problem then this is pretty simple to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will describe an algorithm for doing what you want that hopefully will fulfill your needs.

1. First take the original array of numbers, and split it however you want into 4 arrays of approximately equal size (In your example, this could look like (0,1,2,3),(4,5,6,7),(8,9,10,11),(12,13,14,15) if that makes sense). Label these sub-arrays `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3`, `arr4`, respectively.
2. Now, to fill the array, fill the rows as follows: If the row is of an even index (zero-th, second, fourth, etc.), then fill the first element in the row with a radnom number from `arr1`, otherwise if the row is of an odd index, fill the row with a number from the second `arr3`. Then, fill the next element of the array with an random number from the `arr` following the previous one. For example, if the first element of the row was a number from `arr1`, then the next element in the row would be an element of `arr2`, and the following from `arr3`, and then `arr4`, and then back to `arr1`, etc. And that's it.

**Why it works:** In case you're wondering why it works, first consider the 2d array as a graph. Including diagonals, the 2d array becomes a graph with [chromatic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticNumber.html) 4, meaning that it takes 4 unique elements to `color` the graph. These colors are basically what `arr1`, ..., `arr4` are, so when filling in the graph with numbers from the `arr`'s we are effectively "coloring" the graph.

To see how the graph is colored, consider a 4x4 array. It can be four colored as such:

```
[[ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ],
 [ 3 , 4 , 1 , 2 ],
 [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ],
 [ 3 , 4 , 1 , 2 ]]
```

Note that this is analagous to what the algorithm above does, but instead of the number 1-4, it gets numbers from the arrays, `arr1`, ... , `arr4`. It is also relatively clear to see that the 4-coloring holds for any `m x n` array, proving the validity of our algorithm (This is not a particularly rigorous proof, but hopefully you get the idea).

There are some things to note. First, you need an initial array of length at least 4 otherwise as if you don't, you will have less than 4 "colors" to work with, and it is easy to see that you cannot color this graph with only 3 colors. Additionally, this algorithm could certainly be improved to, let's say, appear "more random" as right now, while the numbers are distributed equally, they will appear not be very random, as a number from `arr1` for example will only be able to be found in certain places in the final array. However, this algorithm does distribute the numbers roughly equally (best if `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3`, `arr4` are all the same size) and does what the question asks, so I believe it is valid.

For more reading about graph coloring, I would recommend reading the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) (more math intensive), or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgbK43jB4rQ) cool problem that is related (4 color map theorem, perhaps you're familiar with it?).

Hope this answer helps, leave a comment question if you have any.